# Validating Form for Class-based view

Tags: django, validation, django-views, django-forms, django-validation

I hope you guys could tell me how to use validation methods in my forms.py for a single field. My view is a `generic.FormView` and my form is `forms.Form`. Here is my view:

```
class ClassSetupView(OrganisorAndLoginRequiredMixin, generic.FormView):
    template_name = "leads/class_setup.html"
    form_class = ClassSetupForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("class-setup-sucess-page")
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Some Other Code
        return super(ClassSetupView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Here is my form:

```
class ClassSetupForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(help_text="Year-01-01",)
    
    clean_date(self):
        date = self.cleaned_data['date']

        if date < datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError(_('Invalid date - renewal in past'))

        return date
```

I hope you guys could tell me if it is okay to use the `clean_date(self)` for the form as a way to validate the field `date`. I saw several examples online, but I am not sure if `clean_date(self)` will work for my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to use clean methods for validation. Check out the official django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just for knowledge next time, can I use the clean method for any type of view(whether function or class-based)?

Comment: @codebuilder You can use forms anywhere in your app but the clean methods are in the interface of Django forms so they're meant to be written inside form classes as you did.

Comment: Oh. I meant does the type of the view (that the form is linked to) matter when using the clean methods in the form? To be specific, can I use the clean methods for any type of form(such `ModelForm` or `Form`) which is linked to any type of view(such as function and class-based)?